# Magento 2.1.9 PayFlow pro - Transaction Declined issues

Tags: magento-2.1.9, paypal-payflow-pro

I configured PayFlow Pro on Magento 2.1.9 and I tried Test mode which seems to work fine, however when switching to Live mode, I'm getting the following Result from the debug log.

```
'RESULT' => '12',
'RESPMSG' => 'Declined',
'HOSTCODE' => '58', (or) '57'
```

I've gone through with the following link from [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/why-did-i-get-result-code-12-ts1234) to go through with the issue but I feel everything fine (IDK if I need to check with Card Issuer (I also tried using Different Cards))

**UPDATED:**

This issue is only related to Australian based PayFlow Pro setup. which uses the processor PayPal Australia in your Payflow account.

**Cause:**

1. Payment Processor: PayPal Australia didn't accept $0 Authorization which is sent by Magento 2 as default.

**How to Resolve This?**

I have answered it. please review and put your comment if you have a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the Model `Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Request\SecureToken` from PayPal using `di.xml` as below in your custom module (Hope you know to do that).

Create: **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Request\SecureToken" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Payflow\Service\Request\SecureToken" />
</config>
```

Now create a Model Rewrite for SecureToken,

Create: **Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Payflow\Service\Request\SecureToken**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Payflow\Service\Request;

use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent;
use Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

/**
 * Class SecureToken
 */
class SecureToken extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Request\SecureToken
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var Random
     */
    private $mathRandom;

    /**
     * @var Transparent
     */
    private $transparent;

    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $url
     * @param Random $mathRandom
     * @param Transparent $transparent
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $url,
        Random $mathRandom,
        Transparent $transparent
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->transparent = $transparent;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Secure Token from Paypal for TR
     *
     * @param Quote $quote
     *
     * @return DataObject
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function requestToken(Quote $quote)
    {
        $request = $this->transparent->buildBasicRequest();
        $request->setTrxtype(Payflowpro::TRXTYPE_AUTH_ONLY);
        $request->setVerbosity('HIGH');
        $request->setAmt(1); // Set authorization amount as 1 by default its 0
        $request->setCurrency($quote->getBaseCurrencyCode());
        $request->setCreatesecuretoken('Y');
        $request->setSecuretokenid($this->mathRandom->getUniqueHash());
        $request->setReturnurl($this->url->getUrl('paypal/transparent/response'));
        $request->setErrorurl($this->url->getUrl('paypal/transparent/response'));
        $request->setCancelurl($this->url->getUrl('paypal/transparent/cancel'));
        $request->setDisablereceipt('TRUE');
        $request->setSilenttran('TRUE');
        $this->transparent->fillCustomerContacts($quote, $request);
        $result = $this->transparent->postRequest($request, $this->transparent->getConfig());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Changes Made in the above file is `$request->setAmt(0);` to `$request->setAmt(1);`.

This resolved the transaction declined issue from the PayPal Australia Processor.

Comment: I am getting Verified: 10574-This card authorization verification is not a payment transaction error. Can you give solution for that? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295614/i-am-getting-verified-10574-this-card-authorization-verification-is-not-a-payme