# I am getting Verified: 10574-This card authorization verification is not a payment transaction in magento 2 for payflow pro credit card transaction

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, paypal-payflow-pro

When I testing the credit card transaction in Magento 2 checkout it is showing 
Refused to display 'https://xxx/paypal/transparent/response/' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny' in the console.

When I checked in the payment.log file it is returning the response message as 
Verified: 10574-This card authorization verification is not a payment transaction. I am using payflow pro. I followed all other solutions to fix this. But still, it remains the same. Kindly help me.

Comment: Hello, Have u found any solution for this and I am facing the same issue. Could u pls help me out

Comment: Are you using paypal pro?

Comment: Hello, yes I am using PayPal pro. Any solution?

Comment: Maybe you can check this -> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/I-am-getting-Verified-10574-This-card-authorization-verification/m-p/338462#M11622